# Is it possible to do form validation from a separate php script?

Tags: php

What I'm trying is a php form validation from a separate file.(form.php & validate.php).
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I think the above comment should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: seriously? someone upvoted this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to include the scripts and you have access to functions inside of them. You really couldn't google this one?

```
include("validate.php"); //inside form.php
```